# How can i transfer one view form to another view in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, .net-4.0

Can anyone help with transferring form from one view to another in MVC3/C#?

Here is the scenario:

1) I have create page where i have about 6 field for user to enter once user submit that field it will redirect them to review page.

2) Once user come on the review page, the information he entered in the create page should appear there (for user to confirm).

3) There will be a edit button on the review page so if the user clicks on the edit button then he should go back to the create page where he had entered all information, so he can update them again.

Can we handle this scenario using ViewData/ViewBag or partial view? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: PartialView is good enought to implement your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class in your Models folder, let's call it MyViewModel, and you'll define in that class all the 6 property you need the user to edit.
In the **create** view, you'll present all your input field inside a form element defined to postback to your **review** action. The significant part of your view, will be:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "MyController"))
{
   //here there's your input field
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.prop1)
   // and so on
}
```

In MyController class, you'll have the Review method defined as following

```
public ActionResult Review(MyModel mm) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(mm);
    } else return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

And at last, in your Review view, you'll have:

```
 @model MyViewModel
 //show up all the field to be reviewed
 @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.prop1)
 //and so on
 // now a form to pastback again all the data to the edit page
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController"))
 {
   //here there's your hidden field
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.prop1)
   // and so on
   <input type="submit" value="Re-edit the fields"/>
 }
```

Your controller class MyController will have the following code:

```
public class ViaggioController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    var emptyModel = new MyViewModel();
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { mm = emptyModel });
}
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel mm) 
{    
    return View(mm);
}

public ActionResult Review(MyViewModel mm) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(mm);
    } 
    else 
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
}
```

Comment: Why do i need to have Redirection to Edit Page:                          public ActionResult Create() 
{
    var emptyModel = new MyViewModel();
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { mm = emptyModel });
}

Comment: I mean Create is my Get Method so it gives me an error if i redirect from there to Edit.

Comment: The idea is that create is nothing but an edit page with a non pre-loaded data, am I right?
Doing this, you can create a brand new (empty) model, and reuse your edit action. Or you could prepare your empty model and use another view passing the model to another view with `return View("Edit", mm);` as you prefer

Comment: what kind of error do you receive? (PS: I write the code on-fly here on the site, maybe I made some mistake... but it should give you the idea)

Comment: no you haven't made any mistake...it's working now :) Thanks a bunch! only thing i don't need is these two lines:  var emptyModel = new MyViewModel(); return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { mm = emptyModel });

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Asp.Net MVC, so I assume your Create View is backed by a Model object that holds the 6 fields that the user enters, and you are using the built in [Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) ?  If so, all you need to do is:

1. Upon a form post to your Create Controller Httpost Action, and the Model state is valid, redirect to your Review Controller, passing it the same Model object using TempData[].
2. Your Review Controller will serve a View to display the Model object's contents.  Implement an edit link on that view which will invoke the Create Controller.  You will need some way to pass the same model back to the Create Controller.  You can probably use TempData[] or a Session veriable to do this.  I don't think you can pass complex objects, i.e. your Model using the ActionLink helper.
3. The Create Crontroller Httpost Action will obtain the model and serve up the view for the user to edit their data.

Comment: You can't pass a model in a redirect. You can, however, return the edit view from a postback.

Comment: yes i have the view model for the 6 field. can you explain me with the example like how to pass viewmodel object from create active to review action, and from review to edit(which is create with filled information) within same controller.

Comment: @updev TempData[] or Session varaibles should work off the top of my head.  There might be other ways too.

Comment: Ok i got the review page with the same model as create as I am redirecting from create to review, return RedirectToAction("Review", myViewModel);                                                                                           Now how can I go back to create page using Edit button from review page with filled information, means using same model object?

Comment: @updev Okay for your Edit button, invoke an action on your review controller.  The review controller will save the model into TempData[], and then redirect to an Create controller action which will obtain the model from TempData[] and display the create view with the model.  I think this should work.